# Defragmentation of a Program's Heap Memory

Tags: c

In C, I understand fragmentation is when most of memory is being allocated in non-contiguous blocks which leaves most of the other memory unallocated then leading to it becoming unusable in most cases. What is still unclear to me is what necessary steps are needed in order for defragmentation of a programs heap memory? If this is done carelessly or incorrectly, what problems can this cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is updating all of the pointers to point to the new memory location, and in unsafe/unmanaged languages like C, it's undecidable whether any given piece of memory will be used as a pointer. If you guess wrong, you get memory corruption the next time it's used. (Solving this is a subset of building a garbage collector for C.)

Comment: That makes sense. With that being said, what would be the necessary steps to avoid this issue and perform a correct defragmentation of the programs heap memory?

Comment: That's REALLY broad. Look up attempts to build a garbage collector for C, and see what hurdles they faced.